# Sudden increase in my CPU usage during random moments(Win Server 2012)

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012, central-processing-unit, process, cpu-usage

At random times, no matter if I am online or not I see that my server having increased Process usage spikes, as you can see in the picture:

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/ve69lc.jpg]

So I go inside the Dashboard on the Server Manager, look at the CPU alerts and see what programs was running. Everything looks like normal:

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/6qacz9.jpg]

I can't see the CPU usage but the threads look like the same.

Is there a way for me to see what caused this increased CPU usage during a certain time to see who the bad boy is, or will I have to wait in the task manager for 1-3 hours to see when the next spike happens and what is causing it?

Best Regards 
Simon

Comment: Sorry for the images, I don't have enough reputation to make a images directly. Also I failed with tinypic, here is a better one: 
First: http://oi57.tinypic.com/ve69lc.jpg 
second: http://oi57.tinypic.com/6qacz9.jpg

Comment: I have been going through my Event Viewer but there is nothing there that matches the time on when these event occurs. I will keep searching to see if I can find a answer to myself and to people having same issue in the future.